# Can a (Delphi) desktop-bridge app be restarted via the windows.updateTasks Extension?

Tags: delphi, background-process, desktop-bridge

I have successfully packaged a Delphi app in an MSIX container, but I've run into a problem with one of my app's requirements:  Upon updating the app from the Store, its background process (a console `exe`) is shut down (of course) and replaced with a new copy that is designated in `AppxManifest.xml` to run when the main app is first opened:

```
<Extensions>
   <desktop:Extension Category="windows.startupTask" Executable="CwHelper.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <desktop:StartupTask TaskId="CwHelper" Enabled="true" DisplayName="Capture Manager" />
   </desktop:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

This all works fine, but it means that the background `exe` is left not running until the main app is opened subsequent to the update. This is highly undesirable.

My Internet spelunking of the MSFT docs leads me to think that I should be able to automatically restart the background app by inserting into the above `<Extensions>...</Extensions>` block a second `Extension` something like this:

```
<Extension Category="windows.updateTask" Executable="<some>.exe" EntryPoint="<some entrypoint>" >
</Extension>
```

So far, I have not been able to discover what should be my (Delphi-created) `<some>.exe` and its `EntryPoint`.  Indeed, I have not found any example of this specific use of that `Extension Category`. Can it actually be used in this way by a desktop-bridge app?  If so, can anyone give me pointers as to what I should put into those blanks?

Note added:  I've tried repeating the `exe`'s name and `Windows.FullTrustApplication` in the `updateTask` definition fields and that actually passed Certification, but it generates a fatal downloading error when the Store tries to install it.

Another note added:  @StefanWick kindly pointed out that he has published an example of the very thing I need [here](https://stefanwick.com/2017/06/06/updatetask-for-desktop-bridge-apps/) using MSFT's toolset.  Unfortunately, it is not clear to me how to translate his C# and Visual Studio labels into a Delphi app.  Any advice on that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after about a month's research, I found out that the answer for now is "no" because the necessary `IBackgroundTasks` interface is not (yet?) available to Delphi according to Embarcadero Customer Support.

But the good news is that this is probably not needed because the "right" way to restart an app after a Store update is described in MSFT docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#restart-automatically-after-receiving-an-update-from-the-microsoft-store).